# Type classes & instances: Pattern parameter becoming a list -- or not?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, typeclass

Haskell newbie here -- I ran into this issue yesterday that I just can't wrap my head around.

### Minimum Working Example

It might not be so minimal, but it demonstrates my issue -- here goes:

```hs
data VectorFeatureSet feature = VFS [feature]

class FeatureSet fs where
    getFeatures :: fs fl -> fl
instance FeatureSet VectorFeatureSet where
    getFeatures (VFS fl) = fl              -- <- error occurs here
```

*(Background info:)* A short comment on what these types mean: a `Feature` is a geographical entity that has a shape and optionally some attributes. A `FeatureSet` is just a group of `Feature`s that belong together.

**The error that the compiler throws on the last line of this code snippet:**

```
Couldn't match expected type `fl' with actual type `[fl]'
  `fl' is a rigid type variable bound by
       the type signature for getFeatures :: VectorFeatureSet fl -> fl
       at (mentioned line)
In the expression: fl
In an equation for `getFeatures': getFeatures (VFS fl) = fl
In the instance declaration for `FeatureSet VectorFeatureSet'
```

If I change the function definition to

```
getFeatures (VFS [fl]) = fl
```

the compiler accepts it.

(Side note: I know that Haskell can create selector functions for me if I use named field notation, but I'm currently learning Haskell so I'm hand-writing these on purpose.)

### Question

Now, the `getFeatures` function should serve simply to extract the list of features from the FeatureSet. My understanding of patterns is that if I don't need to access/process the contents of a list, I don't need to specify a pattern parameter with the list notation, but can just take the list from the pattern and return it in the function.

But here, Haskell wants me to use a function definition like `fs -> [fl] -> fl` to bind a signature like `fs -> fl -> fl` (at least, that's how I understand it).

So my **question** here is: Why is the type of the pattern parameter `fl` different on the left and right hand side of the equation of the function definition?

I feel like I'm missing some fundamental piece here, but I cannot figure out what part of the basics to go back to to get this straight :(

Comment: Note that, while this is labeled "minimum working example", all the stuff about Vector and VectorFeature don't influence the problem at all. You could simplify the problem by removing them and leaving just the last `data`/`class`/`instance` stanza.

Comment: @amalloy thanks, that's totally right! I just edited to make the example smaller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the definition of `VectorFeatureSet`, the constructor `VFS` has type `[fl] -> VectorFeatureSet fl`, i.e. the value it "contains" will be a *list* of `fl`.

In your instance for `FeatureSet`, `getFeatures` should have type `VectorFeatureSet fl -> fl`.

So when you write `getFeatures (VFS fl) = fl`, you are returning a list of features, not a single feature, because the *variable* `fl` has *type* `[fl]` - note that types and variables live in different namespaces.

That's what the type error is telling you - the function was expected to return something of type `fl` but actually produced something of type `[fl]`.

When you write `getFeatures (VFS [fl]) = fl`, you are actually *pattern-matching* for a single-element list, and so your function will fail if you try to call it with either `VectorFeatureSet []` or `VectorFeatureSet [x,y]` etc.

Given the name of `getFeatures` and your description of it, it sounds like it should be defined as

```
class FeatureSet fs where
    getFeatures :: fs fl -> [fl]
```